# Copy Excel data to Whatsapp in image format using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I want to copy excel data from excel sheet and paste it on whatsapp to send message in screenshot or jpeg format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFJYb.png)

Please check attached screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBhKw.png)

i want to copy and paste excel data as seen in screenshots using python.

Below is the code i am using but result is like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ALY.png)

I am expecting the result like this:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBhKw.png)

```
Python code:-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import pyperclip

# Loading dataset


raw_data=r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python SLA\Down Vs Severity and open tickets Files\NMS & EMS          STATUS.xlsx"

NMS_data= pd.read_excel(raw_data,sheet_name='Monitor Status',usecols=['IP     Address','Comments','Monitor Name', 'Type', 'IP Address', 'Availability Status', 'Severity',
   'Ticket Status',],index_col='Monitor Name')

# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
print(" Loading Whatsapp Web page")
driver.maximize_window()

print(" Please scan QR code to Loging")

    # Replace 'Friend's Name' with the name of your friend
# or the name of a group
target = 'My airtel'

# Replace the below string with your own message
excel_data = NMS_data[NMS_data['Comments']=='Need to Enable']


group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p')))

group_title.send_keys(target)

time.sleep(1)

selct_grp = driver.find_element('xpath','/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(1)

set_msg =wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]')))
time.sleep(1)

# copy data to clipboard
excel_data.to_clipboard(sep='|', index=True)

# Simulate the keyboard shortcut for pasting the table content

set_msg =wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]'))).click()
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(2)`
```